# Align the last list item to right side

Tags: css

Could somebody help me with a little problem.

I want to move language selection button to right side of my menu. So it would be separated from other menu links.

I don't know which code lines to modify, that it will affect only language selection button.

My webpage is: avorest.com

My template screenshot to illustrate my question: http://www.upload.ee/image/4823535/Untitled-2.png

My template CSS: http://pastebin.com/Aw1fjsTx

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the parent element to occupy full width. Then target your language list item to be positioned absolute to the right of the menu.

```css
.menu-primary-container {
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-primary {
  width: 100%;
}
.menus li.lang-item {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Language list item menu]